# Bluetooth headphone no longer connect in Linux after succesfully having connected in Windows

Tags: linux, bluetooth, windows-11

I have a JBL Tune 510 BT headphone, which I had been sucessfully using on Debian GNU/Linux until last Saturday.

To connect, I had been using `bluetoothctl` version 5.65.

This Saturday I paired my headphone with Windows 11 for the first time. It worked fine. However, when I booted back on Linux, I could no longer connect to the headphone.

I start the headphone in discovery mode, it makes a "ping" sound, and then I run `bluetoothctl connect`. Tailing `syslog`, I see the following:

> bluetoothd[641]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to MAC-ADDRESS: Connection refused (111)
> bluetoothd[641]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to MAC-ADDRESS: Connection refused (111)

I already attempted to reset the headphone by holding Volume Up and Down, [as indicated here](https://merelymusic.com/how-to-reset-jbl-bluetooth-headphones-all-jbl-models-included/). The error messages above were my attempt to connect *after* resetting.

Comment: Did you try to _pair_ the headphones via bluetootctl after resetting them?

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: So full steps were: reset, remove, then pair again. If you'd like to write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically Bluetooth pairing keys are stored by the OS, so although Linux and Windows share the same Bluetooth MAC address (appearing as a single device), they keep track of pairings independently from each other.

After you've paired the headphones with Windows, the headphones stored the new link keys for the computer's MAC address and discarded the old ones previously created by the Linux pairing (with the assumption that the computer did the same). However, Linux still thinks it's paired – it has the *old* keys stored in /var/lib and attempts to use them when connecting.

You have to completely remove the headphones from bluetoothd and pair them again. (This will make them stop working on Windows.)

---

I used to have [an article](https://nullroute.lt/%7Egrawity/bluetooth-key-sharing.html) about manually copying the link keys from Windows Registry to the Linux bluetoothd configuration so that the same pairing could be shared across both operating systems, but the article was written for WinXP and BT 2.0, so it most likely needs an update for Windows 10 and/or the new pairing protocol that came with Bluetooth 4.x – last I checked, the keys are a bit different now.

Comment: That's it. For people using `bluetoothctl`, the steps I took were `remove MAC`, then `pair MAC`, then `connect MAC`.

Comment: I have been searching for 2 hours, tried all kinds of firmware patches and reboots and manual commands and... doing remove and add like you said just... worked ! I'm aghast.